# Tkinter Frame not destroying/updating

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, frame

I'm trying to update a frame by deleting an old frame, and adding a new one to the grid. I am able to add the new frame to the grid, but the old frame doesn't seem to be deleting, thus the new frame and the old frame are placed on top of each other, and it looks messy. How would I go about fixing this? Below is the general gist of my code.

```
def buttonGet(frame, root, top):
    frame.destroy()
    bottomFrame = Frame(root)
    bottomFrame.grid(row=1, column=0)
    #Adding things to Bottom Frame

def mainForecast(root):


    topFrame = Frame(root)
    topFrame.grid(row=0, column=0)
    bottomFrame = Frame(root)
    bottomFrame.grid(row=1, column=0)

    #Lables, Buttons, Entries within each frame


    label1 = Label(topFrame, font=TruckingFont, text="label1")
    label1.grid(row=1, column=2, rowspan=4, columnspan=2)

    button1 = Button(topFrame, text="Retrieve Current Information", width=45, command=lambda: buttonGet(bottomFrame, root, topFrame))
    button1.grid(row=5, column=0, columnspan=2)



    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: use `bottomFrame.grid_forget()` to remove old frame (before you create new one).

Comment: @furas: destroying the frame is better. Calling `grid_forget()` without destroying the old one is a memory leak. And if you destroy it, you don't need to call `grid_forget()`.

Comment: 'grid_forget()', 'destroy()', and 'grid_remove()' are all not working. The problem seems to be deeper than the method to hide/destroy the frame. Any suggestions?

Comment: @ViggieSmalls: one problem is that you're using local variables. I'm guessing the very first time it may delete the window, but every time after that it's not?

Comment: @BryanOakley Yes that seems about right. Should I make bottomFrame a global variable then?